# Pull certain text from a string that appears after certain characters

Tags: php, string

I am trying to pull certain info from the string below. I’ve tried using explode (which worked) but it is a bit of a long winded procedure. I was wondering if there was a easier, logical way to do it?

An example of the string:

```
string(778) "Automatic reminders periodic maintenance schedule

You have a maintenance schedule
Vehicle:          357207058078957
Task:             Service NA61 HNB
Rule:             Every 10 mi or every 1 months after completion.
                     Task repeats when it is marked as completed
Last excuted:     
Scheduled for:    23/11/2013 or 50720 mi
Due:              since 45 d or in 50719 mi
Reminder:         22/11/2013 or 50715 mi

*** This is an automatically generated email, please do not reply. ***

If you have a question about our products and solutions, you can find your answer on our website under " frequently asked questions " or under "user guides ".

If you need to contact our Customer Support, please use our online contact form.

Kind regards"
```

I need to pull the following info from this example. This info won't always be the same, but the text before it (“Vehicle:”, etc.) will.

- Vehicle: 357207058078957
- Task: Service NA61 HNB
- Rule: Every 10 mi or every 1 months after completion. Task repeats when it is marked as completed
- Last excuted:  (there should be a date here, but sometimes it can be blank).
- Scheduled for:    23/11/2013 or 50720 mi
- Due:              since 45 d or in 50719 mi
- Reminder:         22/11/2013 or 50715 mi

(Note: This is not real data.)

Other than that, the rest can be disregarded.

It doesn’t make a difference whether or not they still have the first bit (e.g Vehicle:), I can easily remove that bit myself.

Comment: As long as that text stays relatively static around the data you're interested in, a series of regex patterns will suss the information out. Try http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ or http://regexpal.com/ to craft the regex. Do it in individual parts, then you may be able to combine it into a single expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned everything up and the final RegEx I have is:

```
/Vehicle:(.*?)\nTask:(.*?)\nRule:(.*?)\nLast excuted:(.*?)\nScheduled for:(.*?)\nDue:(.*?)\nReminder:(.*?)\n\*/s
```

**Breakdown:**

Things in `()` are called match groups.  So we look for `Vehicle:` and then match `.` (everything) for `*` (0+ times).  The `?` is necessary in here to make these lazy matches, not greedy matches..so `.*` stops running when it hits the following character `\nTask:`.  This keeps going until the end, where we get everything up to the trailing `\*` (an escaped *).  Don't forget the `/s` modifier at the ends which allows `.` to match everything *including* newlines.

To implement that in PHP, you would do something as follows:

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
Automatic reminders periodic maintenance schedule

You have a maintenance schedule
Vehicle:          357207058078957
Task:             Service NA61 HNB
Rule:             Every 10 mi or every 1 months after completion.
                     Task repeats when it is marked as completed
Last excuted:     
Scheduled for:    23/11/2013 or 50720 mi
Due:              since 45 d or in 50719 mi
Reminder:         22/11/2013 or 50715 mi

*** This is an automatically generated email, please do not reply. ***

If you have a question about our products and solutions, you can find your answer on our website under " frequently asked questions " or under "user guides ".

If you need to contact our Customer Support, please use our online contact form.

Kind regards
EOT;

if(preg_match('/Vehicle:(.*?)\nTask:(.*?)\nRule:(.*?)\nLast excuted:(.*?)\nScheduled for:(.*?)\nDue:(.*?)\nReminder:(.*?)\n\*/s', $string, $matches)) {
    unset($matches[0]); // $matches[0] contains the whole matches string

    // Update the keys to something more logical
    $keys = array('vehicle', 'task', 'rule', 'last_executed', 'scheduled_for', 'due', 'reminder');
    $data = array_combine($keys, $matches);

    // Trim the values, since we lazy selected in RegEx
    // Note: you may want to do something more complicated, since `rule` still has whitespace
    $data = array_map('trim', $data);

    print_r($data);
    // Array (
    //   [vehicle] => 357207058078957
    //   [task] => Service NA61 HNB
    //   [rule] => Every 10 mi or every 1 months after completion. Task repeats when it is marked as completed
    //   [last_executed] =>
    //   [scheduled_for] => 23/11/2013 or 50720 mi
    //   [due] => since 45 d or in 50719 mi
    //   [reminder] => 22/11/2013 or 50715 mi
    // )
}
?>
```

To learn more read up on [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) on [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace).

Comment: Hi Sam, that sounds a lot better than lots of explode's. However, this worked for me in gskinner.com/RegExr (thanks chris) but it won't work in PHP, it simply displays a blank page... I think this is because the string could be slightly different - I simply echo'd the string and copied it here, is there a way to output the string exactly as it is?

Comment: @Smithey93 there could be a number of reasons, but could you try doing a `<?php var_dump($string); ?>` and updating your question?

Comment: And @Smithey93 try my update of making the `(.*)`s to `(.*?)`.  This will make the selector [lazy instead of greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: Hi sam, please see http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QiEM08zn - ive updated the question too :-).

Comment: Updating, give me a few.

Comment: @Smithey93 please read the breakdown, you should take the time to learn regex.  While they can be a pain in the but, they can come in a ton of use.

Comment: I've just read it, its starting to make sense now... however i could never fully understand it as it never seemed to work for me. If i remember right, apache rewrite rules use a similar (if not the same) santex. Thanks again

Comment: Haha, trust me 4 months ago I avoided anything regex. After being forced to use a regex GUI to work through problems, I consider myself quite advanced in them.  It takes a while, but the more expressions you write the more they will start to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

While Sam's solution is a lot cleaner, I just don't trust Regexpessions yet lol...

Anyways, I didn't see the reply here, but I went ahead and typed this out so I figured I'd post it anyways.

```
$msg ="Automatic reminders periodic maintenance schedule You have a maintenance schedule Vehicle: 357207058078957 Task: Service NA61 HNB Rule: Every 10 mi or every 1 months after completion. Task repeats when it is marked as completed Last excuted: Scheduled for: 23/11/2013 or 50720 mi Due: since 45 d or in 50719 mi Reminder: 22/11/2013 or 50715 mi *** This is an automatically generated email, please do not reply. *** If you have a question about our products and solutions, you can find your answer on our website under \" frequently asked questions \" or under \"user guides\". If you need to contact our Customer Support, please use our online contact form. Kind regards,";
$var = explode(' ',$msg);
$count = 0;
$array_count = 0;
$track_count = true;
$doc = array();
foreach ($var as $word){

    switch ($word) {
        case 'Vehicle:':

            $doc[$array_count] = $var[$count].' '.$var[$count+1];
            $array_count++;
            break;
        case 'Task:':
            $doc[$array_count] = $var[$count].' ';
            $count++;
            for ($i=0; $i <3 ; $i++) { 
                $doc[$array_count] .= $var[$count+$i].' ';
            }
            $array_count++;
            break;
        case 'Rule:':
            $while_count = 0; // run away
            $doc[$array_count] = $word.' ';
            while($var[$count].' '.$var[$count+1] != "Last excuted:"  && $while_count < 30){
                $doc[$array_count] .= $var[$count ].' ';
                $while_count++;
                $count++;
        }
        unset($while_count);
        $array_count++;
        $track_count = false;
        break;
    case 'Last':
        if($var[$count].' '.$var[$count+1] == 'Last excuted:'){
            $while_count = 0; // run away 
            $doc[$array_count] = $var[$count].' '.$var[$count+1];
            $count = $count+2; 
            while($var[$count].' '.$var[$count+1] != 'Scheduled for:'  && $while_count < 30){
                $doc[$array_count] .= $var[$count].' ';
                $while_count++;
                $count++;
            }
        unset($while_count);
        $array_count++;
        break;
        }
    case 'Scheduled':
        if($var[$count].' '.$var[$count+1] == 'Scheduled for:'){
            $while_count = 0; // run away 
            $doc[$array_count] = $word.' '.$var[$count+1].' ';
            $count = $count+2; 
            while($var[$count] != 'Due:'  && $while_count < 30){
                $doc[$array_count] .= $var[$count].' ';
                $while_count++;
                $count++;
            }
            unset($while_count);
        break;
        }
    case 'Due:':
        $while_count = 0; // run away 
        $doc[$array_count] = $word.' ';
        $count++;
        while($var[$count] != 'Reminder:'  && $while_count < 30){
            $doc[$array_count] .= $var[$count].' ';
            $while_count++;
            $count++;
        }
        unset($while_count);
        $array_count++;
        break;
    case 'Reminder:':
        $while_count = 0; // run away 
        $doc[$array_count] = $word.' ';
        $count++;
        while($var[$count] != '***'  && $while_count < 30){
            $doc[$array_count] .= $var[$count].' ';
            $while_count++;
            $count++;
        }
        unset($while_count);
        break;

}

if( $count < count($var)-1 && $track_count ){$count++;}

}
echo '<pre>';var_dump($doc);echo"</pre>";
/*
    array (size=6)
      0 => string 'Vehicle: 357207058078957' (length=24)
      1 => string 'Task: Service NA61 HNB ' (length=23)
      2 => string 'Rule: Every 10 mi or every 1 months after completion. Task repeats when it is marked as completed ' (length=98)
      3 => string 'Last excuted:' (length=13)
      4 => string 'Due: since 45 d or in 50719 mi ' (length=31)
      5 => string 'Reminder: 22/11/2013 or 50715 mi ' (length=33)
*/
```

Glad to see you found a solution